# Sqlite Database not updating values

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

My database is not updating it's values for some reason. According to the tutorials I've been following, I really don't know what could be wrong, here is the code on the databaseAdapter:

```
  public boolean updatePhysicalActivity(String tableName, String recommendation, String activityDate, String activityDistance, String activityTime, String monitor, String activityVelocity ){
     ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
     args.put(RECOMMENDATION,recommendation);
     args.put(ACTIVITY_DATE, activityDate);
     args.put(ACTIVITY_DISTANCE, activityDistance);
     args.put(ACTIVITY_TIME, activityTime);
     args.put(ACTIVITY_VELOCITY, activityVelocity);
     args.put(MONITOR, monitor);
     return db.update(tableName, args, ACTIVITY_DATE + "=" + activityDate, null) > 0;
}
```

I have a few different tables that use the same columns, which is why I name the table when calling the update method. 
I already debugged the program so I know the values are being passed on in this function, but when I check it later, nothing happens. 
Also, I want to update the table that has the same ACTIVITY_DATE value, which is why I use ACTIVITY_DATE instead of KEYID (which was used in the tutorial). Could that be the issue? If so, how do I fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: What data type is the `ACTIVITY_DATE` column in the database?

Comment: and did you try `ACTIVITY_DATE + "='" + activityDate + "'"` as the third argument to `update`?

Comment: @DavidWallace it's VARCHAR

Comment: No I didn't, I'll try right now.

Comment: @DavidWallace it worked! :D However, I now have an exception after updating it too many times... Let's hope I can figure it out.

Comment: What's the message in the exception?

Comment: Completely unrelated to the database apparently... It's a NumberFormatException. I already figured out where it is at, so I should be able to solve it soon enough. Thank you very much though!

Answer (score 0):

The `update` method has the following signature: `update(table, values, whereClause, whereArgs)`

The proper way would be to do:

whereClause:

ACTIVITY_DATE+"=?"

whereArgs:

new String[]{activityDate}

Answer (score 0):

You have omit the single quotations in this line:

```
return db.update(tableName, args, ACTIVITY_DATE + "=" + activityDate, null) > 0;
```

change it to:

```
return db.update(tableName, args, ACTIVITY_DATE + "='" + activityDate +"'", null) > 0;
```